# Google Maps not loading terrain

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I have tried plugins, websites, tutorials, google itself, but no matter what I do, I just cannot get the google map to display the actual "map" part. here is what I mean:

[google map wont display on my site](http://news-linkmedia.com/contact/)

I am now trying to use a wordpress plugin called WPGoole Maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is this style(style.css, line 95)

```
.slide div {
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

these formats will also be applied to the div's in the map-container.

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
#wpgmza_map,#wpgmza_map div {
    background: transparent;
}
```